# How to use jsonb index in postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

My pg is 9.5+.
I have a jsonb data in column 'body':

```
{
   "id":"58cf96481ebf47eba351db3b",
   "JobName":"test",
   "JobDomain":"SAW",
   "JobStatus":"TRIGGERED",
   "JobActivity":"ACTIVE"
}
```

And I create index for body and key:

```
CREATE INDEX scheduledjob_request_id_idx ON "ScheduledJob" USING gin ((body -> 'JobName'));
CREATE INDEX test_index ON "ScheduledJob" USING gin (body jsonb_path_ops)
```

This are my queries:

```
SELECT body FROM "ScheduledJob" WHERE body @> '{"JobName": "analytics_import_transaction_job"}';
SELECT body FROM "ScheduledJob" WHERE (body#>'{JobName}' = '"analytics_import_transaction_job"')  LIMIT 10;
```

Those are return correct data, but no one use index.
I saw the explain:

```
->  Seq Scan on public."ScheduledJob"  (cost=0.00..4.55 rows=1 width=532)
```

So, I don't know why didn't use the index, and how to use the index for jsonb correctly.

**Update:**

- I create index before insert data, the query can use index.
- But I    create index after insert the first data, the query will be
  scan all    records.

This is so strange, and how can I make the index useful when I insert data first.

Comment: Queries with `body#>'{JobName}'` will never use an index of `(body -> 'JobName')`. Use the same expression (i.e. the same operator) to have at least a chance. -- Please post `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of your queries. Your table *may* not contain enough sample rows to use an index.

Comment: In addition to that, for the first index you might be better off using an `INDEX ON "ScheduledJob" USING btree ((body ->> 'JobName'))`.

Comment: My table's row is 900 now. Is this too small to use index?

Comment: I try the btree, but also have the same problem.

Comment: I add the data to 10000 rows, and the query use the index!!! THX!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I do some research and test that:

```
SELECT body FROM "ScheduledJob" WHERE (body#>'{JobName}' = '"analytics_import_transaction_job"')  LIMIT 10;
```

This kind of query will never use the index.

**And only the table have enough data**, index can be available anytime.